# ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, runtime-error, compatibility

I am trying to get `numpy<1.19.0` and `ConfigSpace==0.4.16` to work in a `python==3.7` conda environment. The installed version of `numpy` is `1.18.5`.

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/deephyper/bin/deephyper", line 5, in <module>
    from deephyper.core.cli import main
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/deephyper/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deephyper/core/cli/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from deephyper.core.cli.cli import main
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/deephyper/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deephyper/core/cli/cli.py", line 9, in <module>
    from deephyper.core.cli import hps, nas, balsam_submit
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/deephyper/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deephyper/core/cli/hps.py", line 6, in <module>
    from deephyper.search.util import load_attr_from
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/deephyper/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deephyper/search/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from deephyper.search.search import Search
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/deephyper/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deephyper/search/search.py", line 8, in <module>
    from deephyper.evaluator.evaluate import Evaluator
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/deephyper/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deephyper/evaluator/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from deephyper.evaluator.evaluate import Encoder
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/deephyper/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deephyper/evaluator/evaluate.py", line 15, in <module>
    import skopt
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/deephyper/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skopt/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from . import callbacks
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/deephyper/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skopt/callbacks.py", line 17, in <module>
    from skopt.utils import dump
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/deephyper/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skopt/utils.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .sampler import Sobol, Lhs, Hammersly, Halton, Grid
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/deephyper/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skopt/sampler/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .lhs import Lhs
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/deephyper/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skopt/sampler/lhs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ..space import Space, Categorical
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/deephyper/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skopt/space/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .space import *
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/deephyper/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skopt/space/space.py", line 27, in <module>
    import ConfigSpace as CS
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/deephyper/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ConfigSpace/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from ConfigSpace.configuration_space import Configuration, \
  File "ConfigSpace/configuration_space.pyx", line 39, in init ConfigSpace.configuration_space
  File "ConfigSpace/hyperparameters.pyx", line 1, in init ConfigSpace.hyperparameters
ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject
```

I tried suggested solutions suggested in other similar questions such as trying other versions of `numpy` or removing all `numpy` installations and reinstalling `numpy` and `ConfigSpace` with `pip` options `--no-cache-dir --no-binary`, but the error persists.

Are there other potential solutions that I could try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got some additional insight into the issue by consulting [this GitHub issue page](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12785). As it turns out, if the size from the PyObject is smaller than the size from the C header, an upgrade of the package referenced by the error (here `numpy`) is necessary to resolve the error, and vice versa.

I was able to resolve the issue by upgrading `numpy` to version `1.20.0`, even though the requirement was `numpy<1.19.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing this in case it helps others: I was trying to get [fairseq](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/) to work and ran into the same issue of `ValueError` with binary incompatibility as possible reason and Jake's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65981228/1722863) of updating numpy to `1.20.0` helped solve the problem even through requirements specifically asked for `numpy<1.19.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem: `ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject` and this solution worked for me. Specifically, using Dockerfile to create an image, I install flair==0.8.0.post1, which requires numpy<1.19.0. But after installing flair==0.8.0.post1 I install numpy==1.20.0 and this has avoided the problem. This section of the Dockerfile is:

```
RUN pip install flair==0.8.0.post1
RUN pip install numpy==1.20.0
```